# Why does the SQL SUM() function return a non-zero total when a group float values should add up to 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I am facing this issue with the SQL `SUM()` function I have three values that have the sum equals to zero as you can see the values but with the `SUM()` function the answer is that strange values as shown.

```
select Qty
from Stock
where ProductCode = '5LINE-15-1-30RU'
```

Output:

```
1. 49.72
2. -31.065
3. -18.655
```

Whereas

```
select sum(Qty)
from Stock
where ProductCode = '5LINE-15-1-30RU'
```

Output:

```
-3.5527136788005E-15
```

The result have to be 0 but I got this awkward value.

Column `Qty` is a `float`.

Comment: The datatype for Qty column is float

Comment: For all practical purposes, `-3.5527136788005E-15` is zero.

Comment: I'd suggest to use a ROUND function in order to trim these extra digits, which for the float type could lead to these bizarre 0.0xxxxE-16 results

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using a [`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) datatype which stores values as approximations c.f.

> Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly.

For cases when you need precision, e.g. when you need decimal/int values you should use a `decimal`/`int` datatype. Its pretty rare that you would use a `float`. If you are unable to change the column datatype you can convert it before summing e.g.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (Qty FLOAT);

INSERT INTO @Test (Qty)
VALUES
(49.72),
(-31.065),
(-18.655);

SELECT SUM(Qty)
    , SUM(CONVERT(money,Qty))
FROM @Test;
```

Returns:

| FloatSum | ConvertedSum |
| --- | --- |
| -3.5527136788005E-15 | 0.00 |